Passing logged-in user data without creating a constant in Next-Auth
I'm building a Next.js application that uses the next-auth library for authentication. I have set up Google and Credentials providers, and I'm able to sign in users using both methods.
My question is: Is there a better way to handle the logged-in user data without creating a constant like logInData? I'm worried that this approach might not be the best practice, and I'm wondering if there are any alternative solutions.
In my authOptions configuration, I'm storing the logged-in user data in a variable called logInData like this:
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import {
  SignInWithOauth,
  signInWithCredentials,
} from "@/services/AuthServices";
import { NextAuthOptions, Session } from "next-auth";

let logInData: any = null;   //Is there any better way to do this instead of doing it like this(Its working).
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        userId: {
          label: "userId",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Enter username",
          required: true,
        },
        password: {
          label: "password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Enter password",
          required: true,
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.userId || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid Credentials");
        }
        const { userId, password } = credentials;
        const user = await signInWithCredentials({ userId, password }); //From this function we are getting user data from backend api
        logInData = user;
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (account?.type === "oauth" && profile) {
        const loggedInData = await SignInWithOauth({ account, profile }); ////From this function we are getting user data from backend api if already present , else it is created and new user is returned.
        logInData = loggedInData;
        return true;
      }
      return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, trigger, session }) {
      if (!token?.user && logInData) token.user = logInData;
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token.user) session.user = token.user as Session["user"];
      return session;
    },
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

